# How do you write a Jest test to check if code execution is blocked?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mutex

I am using `async-mutex` I just want to test a functionality for it specifically I want to confirm whether the `Mutex.acquire` method keeps things blocked.

```
it('should remain blocked when accessing the mutex a second time', async () => {
    const mutex = new Mutex();
    const release = await mutex.acquire();
    expect(mutex.isLocked()).toBeTruthy();

    expect( async () => { await mutex.acquire() } ).toStillBeRunningAfterSpecifiedSeconds(5);
  });
```

I tried

```
expect(await mutex.acquire()).toThrow("Timeout");
```

Since I get this message

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it:

```js
describe("async-mutex", () => {
  it("checks that lock is released", (done) => {
    const mutex = new Mutex();

    // releases the lock right after locking it
    mutex.acquire().then((release) => {
      release();

      expect(mutex.isLocked()).toBe(false);

      done();
    });
  });

  it("checks that lock is not released", (done) => {
    // if test is running after 4 seconds, then mutex is still locked
    // done exits this test without errors
    setTimeout(() => {
      done();
    }, 4000);

    const mutex = new Mutex();

    mutex.acquire();

    expect(mutex.isLocked()).toBe(true);

    // this second call to acquire should never run
    // if it does, then the test should fail
    mutex.acquire().then(() => {
      expect(1).toBe(2);
    });
  });
});
```

Now, if you problem is with the duration of the test, you can always increase it using `jest.setTimeout(milliseconds)`.